# Split string array to int array

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I want to convert array of strings, for example

```
str1[][] ={{"1,2,3,4","0","2,1"}};
```

to int array like that:

```
int arr[][]={{1,2,3,4},{0,0,0,0},{2,1,0,0}}
```

Im not able to use just split method, because the size of the tempString changes after every iteration.

My code:

```
int numOfelements = 3;

        String str1[][] = { { "1,2,3,4", "0", "2,1" } };
        int graph[][] = new int[numOfelements][numOfelements];
        String str[]= new String[numOfelements];


            for (int i = 0; i < numOfelements; ++i) {
                str = str1[i][0].split(",");
                for (int j = 0; j < numOfelements; ++j) {
                    try {
                        if (str.length < j)
                            graph[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
                        else
                            graph[i][j] = 0;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Error in the data!",
                                "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I think, instead of `str = str1[i][0].split(",");` you should switch the indices by using `str = str1[0][i].split(",");`

Comment: @Expiredmind Take a look at my solution.

Comment: Is string like `"1,2,3,4,5"` possible? If so it be converted to `{1,2,3,4}` or `{1,2,3,4,5}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write a customized method to fill the array with zeroes. `.split()` still can be used if you use it cautiously.

```
public static int[] fillArray(String s, int size){
    String[] tok = str.split(",");
    int[] newArr = new int[size];

    for(int x=0; x<Math.min(size, tok.length); x++)
        newArr[x] = Integer.parseInt(tok[x]);

    for(int x=Math.min(size, tok.length); x<Math.max(size, tok.length); x++)
        newArr[x] = 0;

    return newArr;
}
```

Get the array data and fill it with zeroes and put it back in a new array:

```
int[][] arr;
for(int x=0; x<str1[0].length; x++)
    arr[0][x] = fillArray(str1[0][x], 4);  //size of 4 can be changed to your needs
```

Comment: I must modify your solution a little but it gives me good clue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this solution :

```
int numOfelements = 4;
        String str1[][] = { { "1,2,3,4", "0", "2,1" }};
        int graph[][] = new int[numOfelements][numOfelements];
        String str[]= new String[numOfelements];

        for (int k = 0; k < str1.length; k++) {
            int len =str1[k].length;    
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                str = str1[k][i].split(",");    
                for(int j = 0; j < str.length; j++ )
                    graph[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(str[j]);
            }
        }
```